# Нужна ли запятая перед «для которых» и перед «на которых»?

Tags: запятые

фотографии для которых улыбаешься

фотографии на которых улыбаешься

Comment: Нужна в обоих случаях. Это союзные слова в придаточном определительном предложении (какие фотографии). И по совместительству члены предложения (для кого улыбаешься, где улыбаешься).

Comment: @Sharon , вчера собрал в один альбом новые твои снимки и фотографии на которых улыбаешься.

Comment: И что? Запятую надо поставить: вчера собрал в один альбом новые твои снимки и фотогрАфии, / на которых улыбАешься.

Comment: Спасибо большое:)